# SharePoint 2013 Listview webpart paging doesn't work for anonymous users

Tags: web-part, 2013, anonymous-authentication, list-view-web-part, paging

If you have an anonymous publishing site in SP2013 and you throw down a list view webpart to any given list the first page renders fine but when the anonymous user tries to go to the next page they are hit with an authentication prompt when trying to post to `inplview.aspx`. If I assign `server render` in webpart properties it works fine, but you lose the nice SP2013 experience. Is the default list view web part not supported on anonymous sites or is this a bug in Sharepoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a workaround](http://code-reflections.blogspot.com/2013/09/sharepoint-2013-anonymous-site-and.html) to at least give you sorting and paging for anonymous users.